# Running application on a older version of .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Over the past few days I have been writing a program to configure HDDs. I had the program up and running and went to test it on the box it will be used on. As I go to test, i realize the target box I will be using it on has a VERY out-dated .net framework. It is 100% my fault I did not think of that in advance, but now I want to see what options I have.

I cannot update the framework on this box. 
I am running the application from a flash drive (is there anyway I can have the framework installed on that and have it work? Not exactly sure how all that is incorporated)

If there is nothing I can do, is there a way to rollback the framework for a single project so I can get it working?

Side Note: Application is a WinForm, written in VB.net

EDIT: Get specifics from the computer - sorry I did not add that in the first place.

EDIT 2: Computer is on Windows Server 2000 running .net Framework 2.0

Comment: What does "very outdated" mean? The earliest supported version is 4.5.2. Anything before 2.0 shouldn't be considered .NET at all. You'll *have* to update it or rewrite *almost everything* with a 13 year old version of Visual Studio

Comment: Have you tried going to "Project"->"<project name> properties" and changing the "Target framework"?

Comment: Could you include the versions running on each box?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- "The earliest supported version is 4.5.2" <-- supported for what?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Why would 4.5.2 be the earliest supported version? In VS 2010 you can target at least .NET 2.0.

Comment: Is the project you are trying to change the target framework of the only one being deployed to the older machine? Or are there multiple project DLLs/EXEe that will end up on the machine?

Comment: Because no version before 4.5.2 is supported any more. The  [end-of-life date for previous versions was January 12, 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/). And VS 2010 is 6 year old. As for more practical reasons than using unsupported .NET versions, TLS1.2 was added in 4.5.2. By sticking with 2.0 people risk losing the ability to use HTTPS as almost everyone has moved to TLS1.1 at least, with many providers requiring TLS1.2

Comment: Complete list of the dates - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework

Comment: Top post updated. It is running 2.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Oh, well by _supported_ I thought you meant supported in VS. -- Personally I miss not being able to use .NET 4.5.x or 4.6.x, but I appreciate VS 2010's design much more than the newer versions. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent "I miss not being able to use .NET 4.5.x or 4.6.x" <--- ??

Comment: @VisualVincent VS 2010 can't use anything beyond 4.0, so you are really missing some of the most important features like Tasks and `async/await`. These things can't be replaced by any previous functionality in a realistic way. And as I said, missing TLS support is a killer, as in going-out-of-business

Comment: @VisualVincent You can still target .NET 2.0 in VS2015.

Comment: @rory.ap : Well I didn't fully know how to phrase it... I'd like to use the newer versions, but I also want to work in a nicely designed environment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Imagine the *target* machine has .NET 2.0 and *cannot* be updated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I am well aware if what I miss, however I don't use TLS/HTTPS and so far I haven't needed `async/await`. I can still use tasks though.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : I suspected you would be able to. Which is why I was confused with what Panagiotis said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application will need to target the "very out-dated" version of .NET, then you'll need to compile your application to target that version, no higher.

Unfortunately, this means you'll lose some features added in later versions.  You also might have trouble with referenced assemblies which target higher versions; those would need to be at or below your .NET version.

The best idea would be to install the later versions of the framework on the machine, but you already said it can't be done.  In that case, I guess you're out of luck (if the above suggestions are not applicable).  You can't reasonably expect old machines to run new software as the gap between their ages widens.

Comment: If "very outdated" means before 2.0, some of the most basic language features will be missing. like generics

Comment: Updated top post, this old box is on 2.0